# How to get gmail logged in user detail using GIDSignIn after app restart in Swift iOS

Tags: swift, gmail-api, gidsignin

I have integrated GIDSignIn in iOS swift project. I am able to login and get user detail like email using.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser?.profile.email
```

But when I kill and restart app `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser` become nil. And I need to sign in silently in app to get the `currentUser` detail. 
Is there any way to get email address of logged in user when app restart without silent sign in?

Comment: Just store the information in UserDefaults or whatever database you use and when you run application you can check the data in defaults to silently login the app

Comment: Yes, I have already implemented that way. I am looking for gmail api to get this detail.

Comment: You could save it in the `Keychain`, if the object contains secret data.

Comment: Yes we can handle it in app in other way like nsuserfault, keychain, etc. But I want to know how we can get it using gmail API